# Drawing/Graphics Libraries for Mono Android and MonoTouch

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

Are there any libraries that utilize the the Canvases for Mono Android and MonoTouch? I am trying to draw node + edge network graphs and am hoping to avoid duplicating work by writing code to figure out methods for edge, node, and text placement (for labeling a node).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure about the edge/node/text placement part of your question, but one project that's recently emerged is https://github.com/praeclarum/CrossGraphics which looks promising for sharing drawing code across the Mono mobile platforms:

> Drawing commands include:
>
> - Rectangles using FillRect and DrawRect
> - Rounded Rectangles using FillRoundedRect and DrawRoundedRect
> - Ovals using FillOval and DrawOval
> - Lines using DrawLine and the option BeginLine and EndLine primitives
> - Images using DrawImage
> - Text using DrawString and the associated font
>     functions

Comment: Thanks! I'll check it out, looks promising.